# Pass parameters to Mscrm.CrmDialog

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, showmodaldialog

I use Mscrm.CrmDialog to show a new dialog with a webresource in MS Dynamics CRM 2013. The advantage of this method is that this dialog works in Firefox, Chrome, etc. too and window.showModalDialog doesn't because it is deprecated.

Anyway I need to pass parameters to the webresource. With window.showModalDialog this was no problem but now when using Mscrm.CrmDialog I couldn't find any way to pass parameters. The constructor has a parameter 'customWindowParameters', but how to access these parameter(s) from the web resource?

Comment: the use of Mscrm.CrmDialog is unsupported

Comment: I know that it is unsupported. But what is a better solution to show a dialog? The deprecated ModalDialog is unsupported by most browsers too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare global variable in the script from where you calling the dialog (Mscrm.CrmDialog) like:

```
var variable1 = 5;
var object1 = { Id: 1, name: "SWA" };

function ribbon_OpenDialog() {
    var clientUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var url = clientUrl + "/WebResources/new_myWebResource.html";
    //CRM 2015 SP 1
    var dialogwindow = new parent.Mscrm.CrmDialog(parent.Mscrm.CrmUri.create(url), this, 450, 175);
    //For CRM less than CRM 2015 SP 1
    //var dialogwindow = new Mscrm.CrmDialog(Mscrm.CrmUri.create(url), this, 450, 175);
    dialogwindow.show();
}
```

The above globally declared variables can be accessed in the webresource through `window.getDialogArguments()` as in the following sample html webresource

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dialog;
        if (window.getDialogArguments() != null) {
            dialog = window.getDialogArguments();
        }
        var v1 = dialog.variable1;
        var o1 = dialog.object1;

        function doSomthing() {
            alert("variable1= " + v1 + "\n object1.Id=" + o1.Id + "\n object1.name=" + o1.name);
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .dvrow {
            clear: both;
            margin: 2px auto 0 auto;
            padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
            width: 96%;
        }
        .headerTitle {
            font-family: Segoe UI Light, Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial;
            font-size: 27px;
            font-weight: lighter;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formPopup">
        <div id="spinner">
        </div>
        <div class="dvrow">
            <div class="headerTitle">
               Test dialog Popup
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button title="Run" id="btnRun" onclick="doSomthing();" type="button">Run</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Click Run button results:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be a proper solution. I've found a second alternative too: you can use the default data-URL-parameter for CRM-webresources: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327945.aspx